# Floating Point Exception - NASM

Tags: floating-point, nasm, x86-64

I'm studying NASM and I don't have any experience. I make this ITOA code, and my idea is to move the remainder (dl) to the third byte of a buffer("-00-") in the first loop, and in the second one to the second byte of the buffer:

```
itoa:
mov rax, rbx
mov rsi, 2
mov r9d, 10


mydiv:

div r9d ;divide my number with 10
and dl, 00001111b   
mov [result + rsi], dl ;move the remainder to my buffer   
dec rsi ;decrease rsi to move the remainder to the second byte in the nxt        loop
xor rdx,rdx  ;clean rdx
cmp rax,0 ;if my quotient is 0, print the buffer, if not, repeat the process
jz print
jmp mydiv
```

But when I try the code, I get a floating point exception! Please help me, I really want to learn the use of div in NASM.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507414/print-int-as-ascii-in-assembly-64-bit-att-float-number-error  (you're not clearing `rdx` prior to the very first division).

Comment: Btw, `and dl, 00001111b` doesn't make any real sense in this function. The remainder will be in the range 0..9, and to convert that to a character in the range '0'..'9' you'll want to do `add dl,'0'`